# Divisors Sum Related Interesting Approximate Relation

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, approximation, divisor-sum

Working on Divisors Sum Efficient calulcation topic. Accidentaly discovered one interesting relation which is accurate up to $10^{17}$ order.
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sigma(i)}{e^{i}}}\approx\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{24}$$

To get things more clear look at the below numbers:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sigma(i)}{e^{i}}}=1.1866007335148928206...$$
$$\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{24}=1.1866007335148931031...$$

Just would like to share this nice relation, check if you know some paper about this and wondering if there are some similar known relations for other number theoretical functions:)

Just to clarify things this is not the only realation, but one of many, for example:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sigma(i)}{\sqrt{e^i}}}\approx\frac{2\pi^2}{3}-1+\frac{1}{24}$$

---

EDITED

Accorging to @Greg Martin comment just realized that this is Lambert Series example.

Lets assume now $s>0$.

So the general rule is
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sigma(i)}{e^{si}}}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{\frac{i}{e^{si}-1}}$$

Using Euler-Maclaurin summation:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{\frac{i}{e^{si}-1}}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{e^{sx}-1}dx - \frac{1}{2}\big(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{e^{sx}-1}+\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{e^{sx}-1}\big)+\frac{1}{12}\big(\lim_{x\to\infty}(\frac{x}{e^{sx}-1})'-\lim_{x\to0}(\frac{x}{e^{sx}-1})'\big)-\frac{1}{720}\big(\lim_{x\to\infty}(\frac{x}{e^{sx}-1})'''-\lim_{x\to0}(\frac{x}{e^{sx}-1})'''\big)+...$$

Here all the higher order derivatives are odd. If we look at the $\frac{x}{e^{sx}-1}$ all the odd derivatives $(\frac{x}{e^{sx}-1})^{(2k-1)}$ at $x\to0$ and $\infty$ are equal $0$ except the first derivative.

Here is the list of few odd derivatives:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\big(\frac{x}{e^{sx}-1}\big)=\frac{1}{s}; \lim_{x\to\infty}\big(\frac{x}{e^{sx}-1}\big)=0$$

$$\lim_{x\to0}\big(\frac{x}{e^{sx}-1}\big)'=-\frac{1}{2}; \lim_{x\to\infty}\big(\frac{x}{e^{sx}-1}\big)'=0$$

$$\lim_{x\to0}\big(\frac{x}{e^{sx}-1}\big)'''=0; \lim_{x\to\infty}\big(\frac{x}{e^{sx}-1}\big)'''=0$$

$$\lim_{x\to0}\big(\frac{x}{e^{sx}-1}\big)^{(5)}=0; \lim_{x\to\infty}\big(\frac{x}{e^{sx}-1}\big)^{(5)}=0$$

and integral equals to $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{e^{sx}-1}dx=\frac{\pi^2}{6s^2}$$

So finally we have:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sigma(i)}{e^{si}}}=\frac{\pi^2}{6s^2}-\frac{1}{2s}+\frac{1}{24}$$

**Conclusion**
Even after above formulas, the calculation shows that the real values are not matching. For example case for $s=1$. **Any idea why this formula does not work?**

Comment: Side note: the two series can be simplified to $\sum_{d=1}^\infty d/(e^d-1)$ and $\sum_{d=1}^\infty d/(e^{d/2}-1)$, respectively.

Comment: I found $\sum_1\sigma(n)e^{-2\pi n}=(1/24)-(1/(8\pi))$ at oeis.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thank you, may I ask to share the link.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A000203

Comment: Note that these are all multiplicative functions so all the above have decomposition in explicit euler products on prime powers

Comment: Answer edited with details.

Comment: Have a look at the update.  When I use $n$ it means that I am using  $(5+2n)$ derivatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using, as you did, Euler-MacLaurin summation, the formula for infinite values of $n$ are a bit more complex.

For example, the expansion around $s=0$ leads to
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{\frac{i}{e^{si}-1}}=\frac{\pi^2}{6s^2}-\frac{1}{2s}+\frac{1}{24}+$$ $$\frac{s^9}{632282112}\left(1-\frac{29332259 s^2}{62107500}+\frac{8569 s^4}{117000}-\frac{19774139 s^6}{2705040000}+O\left(s^8\right) \right)$$

**Edit**

After doing the Euler-MacLaurin expansion,assuming $s>0$ and $n \to \infty$, what is left is
$$\color{blue}{\frac{\text{Li}_2\left(e^{-s}\right)}{s^2}-\frac{\log (1-e^{-s})}{s}+\frac{\sum _{s=0}^7 e^{k s}\,\, P_k(s)}{1209600 \left(e^s-1\right)^8}}$$  where the polynomials are of degree $7$. Starting from the constant term, the list of coefficients are

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & \text{coefficients of } P_k(s) \\
 0 & \{-504000\} \\
 1 & \{3528000,100800,-5040,-1680,200,40,-7,-1\} \\
 2 & \{-10584000,-604800,20160,0,1600,960,-392,-120\} \\
 3 & \{17640000,1512000,-25200,15120,-3800,600,-1715,-1191\} \\
 4 & \{-17640000,-2016000,0,-26880,0,-3200,0,-2416\} \\
 5 & \{10584000,1512000,25200,15120,3800,600,1715,-1191\} \\
 6 & \{-3528000,-604800,-20160,0,-1600,960,392,-120\} \\
 7 & \{504000,100800,5040,-1680,-200,40,7,-1\} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Computed for $s=1$, the decimal representation of the result is
$$1.186600734454629573971129\cdots$$

The next level of Euler-MacLaurin summation formula would give
$$\color{blue}{\frac{\text{Li}_2\left(e^{-s}\right)}{s^2}-\frac{\log (1-e^{-s})}{s}+\frac{\sum _{s=0}^9 e^{k s}\,\, P_k(s)}{239500800\left(e^s-1\right)^{10}}}$$ where the polynomials are of degree $9$.

**Update**

Working directly with $s=1$, which make calculations must faster, and playing with the successive orders of Euler-MacLaurin summation formula, the following results are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \text{result}_n \\
 1 & 1.186600734454629573971129 \\
 2 & 1.186600733577258935824311 \\
 3 & 1.186600733520094925774897 \\
 4 & 1.186600733515372855721243 \\
 5 & 1.186600733514926126548741 \\
 6 & 1.186600733514887173075080 \\
 7 & 1.186600733514887596144576 \\
 8 & 1.186600733514889998560738 \\
 9 & 1.186600733514891409585063 \\
 10 & 1.186600733514892131192378 \\
 11 & 1.186600733514892501128664 \\
 12 & 1.186600733514892697428227 \\
 13 & 1.186600733514892805224178 \\
 14 & 1.186600733514892865159871 \\
 15 & 1.186600733514892896968697 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

which seem to properly coincide with the given value of $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sigma(i)}{e^{i}}}$.

Comment: Thank you. Just wondering is there any segment for $s$ where the Euler-MacLaurin summation is correct? Sorry or you mean that I did the calculations incorrectly?

Comment: @GevorgHmayakyan. No idea ! I am fascinated by this problem. Cheers

Comment: Thanks again, may I ask to share the method how this series estimated? Sorry may be it is obvious.

Comment: Sorry @Claude Leibovici so you mention that only first $7$ derivatives are $0$ at $0$ and $\infty$? And starting from 9, it will not be 0?

Comment: If we look at taylor expansion of the $$\frac{x}{e^{x s}-1} = 1/s - x/2 + (s x^2)/12 - (s^3 x^4)/720 + (s^5 x^6)/30240 - (s^7 x^8)/1209600 + (s^9 x^{10})/47900160 - (691 s^{11} x^{12})/1307674368000 + O(x^{13})$$ odd powers of $x$ are $0$ or $\frac{x}{e^{x s}-1} + x/2$ is even. So how do we get odd derivatives equal to not $0$. Sorry may be it is obvious I just can not get it.

Comment: @GevorgHmayakyan. Do not use limits. Keep the derivatives up to the end. If you take the sixth derivative it is $\frac{s^5}{42}-\frac{s^7 x^2}{60}+O\left(x^4\right)$ and the seventh is  $-\frac{s^7 x}{30}+\frac{5 s^9 x^3}{396}+O\left(x^5\right)$

Comment: thank you for your explanation.

Comment: Sorry @ClaudeLeibovici may I ask to double check the result, as the correct answer for $s=1$ is $1.1866007335148928206$?

Comment: Those are the first 20 digits.